# 404 Redirect is Not Working for pages in a file structure not on my hosting

Tags: css, redirect, http-status-code-404

I recently did some major updates to a website I have www.dcmobileads.com

I had about 20 subpages and I trimmed it down to less than 10. Many of these subpages were in a Folder entitled "content" on my GoDaddy hosting account. I removed this folder entirely.

When I do a specific Google search, www.dcmobileads.com/content/washington-dc-mobile-billboards.html is one of the results that rank, even though the folder "content" no longer exists. When I click the link on the search results, the result is a page at the exact path instead of the 404 redirect that I set to go to my homepage. The page which is displayed is a mess and it does not have the CSS style sheet.

I am baffled as to why there is not a redirect to my home page, especially since the file structure  and folder CONTENT is no longer up.

ANy help would be appreciated greatly!

Comment: The link you shared is absolutely up that is why you are seeing it. Maybe you forgot to restructure the "content" folder.

Comment: The content folder has been deleted. Interestingly, if I enter my URL with /non-existent-folder in the path it redirects fine, but if I enter my URL with /non-existent-folder/ in the path, I get  redirected to my home page that does not display properly as it does not reference the style sheet.